# Conservative method of tying tzitzis?

Tags: minhag, tzitzis

I recently came into possession of a 4-cornered garment with *tzitziyos* attached to its corners that was previously owned (although not necessarily worn or endorsed) by a non-Conservative member of a Conservative synagogue.

There were four sections of windings, with approximately 4-6-10-12 winds respectively. (It is often hard to tell if a circuit is complete when they don't start and end at the same axial place.) The sections were made by winding two strings around rather than one.

This method of tying is one I've never seen before and I wanted to know if it is an identifiable *minhag*, and if it is indeed the standard Conservative method of tying.

Comment: FWIW, that's not what the loaner talitot in the Conservative shul where I daven weekdays look like.

Comment: it can also be that the person who made those tzizts has no clue how to properly affix them onto to the talis

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either a mistake in your counting of the wraps or a mistake on the person who tied the tzitzis. The Conservative Movement uses the traditional Ashkenazi minhag for tzitzis, which has 7, 8, 11, 13 wrap method.